# On the irreducibility of the prime spectrum

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

I came accross this question [Why is the prime spectrum of a domain irreducible in the Zariski topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/20721/why-is-the-prime-spectrum-of-a-domain-irreducible-in-the-zariski-topology)

I wonder if the converse is true. That is, given the prime spectrum of a ring which happens to be irreducible, is it true that the ring is an integral domain? I know there is a general fact that the prime spectrum is irreducible iff the nilradical is prime, but one cannot apply this because the fact that the nilradical is prime does not imply that the ring is a domain.

Comment: What about the prime spectrum of a local ring?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You already disproved the converse with the characterization in terms of the nilradical. Since there are rings where the nilradical is prime that are not domains, there are rings whose spectrums are irreducible that are not domains.